# How to make the default value a reference to a field from another table while still being able to edit the new field in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

How to make the default value a reference to a field from another table while still being able to edit the new field in Microsoft Access?

Ideally, I’d like to find a solution that doesn’t include the use of VBA coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Access 2010 or 2013 you can use the macro event "After Insert Macro Event"

Here is the official description from Microsoft
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196099(v=office.14).aspx

You should examine the Example and build an appropriate version in your database for your needs.